# "subscript out of range" in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting "subscript out of range" in excel vba at the line `"Workbooks("source").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate"`

```
Sub one()
    Dim target As Object
    Set target = ThisWorkbook

    source = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Excel 2003 (*.xls),*.xls,Excel 2007 (*.xlsx),*.xlsx,Excel 2007 (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", _
        Title:="Select an the sdlc workbook", _
        MultiSelect:=File)
    If source = False Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=source
    End If
    Workbooks("source").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: check both names: `source` for workbook and `sheet1` for sheet if they exist and are correct. If you have that workbook saved then you should rather type name with extension, like `source.xlsx` or other extension.

Comment: First, what is `File` in `MultiSelect` argument? I believe it is either `True` or `False`. As for the other, check what @KazJaw commented and get back here.

Answer (score 0):

It appears `source` is a variable, not the actual name of the workbook. It would be easier to use a `Workbook` variable rather than the name:

```
Sub one()
    Dim target As Excel.Workbook
    Set target = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wbSource as Excel.Workbook

    source = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Excel 2003 (*.xls),*.xls,Excel 2007 (*.xlsx),*.xlsx,Excel 2007 (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", _
        Title:="Select an the sdlc workbook", _
        MultiSelect:=File)
    If source = False Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=source)
    End If
    wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub
```